# How to make an edittext both signed and decimal?

Tags: android, variables, android-edittext

is there a way to change edittext settings to both decimal (3.4) and singed(+/-)?
and what tipe of variable should i set in my activity?
I tried with decimal, number and signed but i want to use a number like -3.6 and to store it in my activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your activity class:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

from [InputType | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

OR:

In your activity class:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.-"));
```

That allows the `EditText` to input decimals and negative signs, as you can see at the end of the line.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

OR:

In your `EditText` XML properties, add this property:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

You can input the number to a `String` to store the value inputted:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
String userInput = editText.getText().toString();
```

`userInput` will then be equal to the String that the user inputted. To convert it to a double, you can do this:

```
// however, this will break your app if you convert an empty String to a double
// so if there could be no text in the EditText, use a try-catch
double userInputDouble = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
```